# How to keep User IAM credentials private?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I am new to AWS so not fully aware of its features.

I want to create an application running on EC2 instance which allows a user to login and upload a picture to a S3 bucket.

The user is created in through IAM in AWS, and assigned a policy to allow that specific user to only access that specific bucket.

However, in my code, I do not want to store the Access ID and the Secret key - which is assigned by AWS when I create my user due to Security issues i.e. in case someone gets access to them.

In order to solve this, my thoughts were to create my own login system, where I create a user (e.g. user = abc1, password = password1), and in the background the user and password will be equal to the access key and the secret ID without the user ever knowing them.

Is this a good way forward with this and how would I go ahead with it? Or is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

This is my recommendation:

Build your own login system (typical login/password(hashed) system), and assign an IAM user to the application itself (or the machine with a machine role), not the user, so the application (or machine) is the entity allowed to run the S3 operations. This way is easier to manage privileges.

Comment: How do I assign an IAM user to the application? And how would this work with many IAM users?

Comment: When you create an IAM user you are allowed to add a key/secret access to work with the API, use that with the application to access AWS services through the API.